# Achartengine XY series label

Tags: android, achartengine

Is it possible to align the XYseriesrenderer lable to particular angle similar to rotating the X & Y lables in multirenderer in achart engine ?

Comment: What is the XYSeriesRenderer label?

Comment: Its the label above each bar in the bar chart